# Как изменить вид скроллбара?

Tags: javascript, css3, вёрстка

Здравствуйте.
С помощью чего можно изменить внешний вид скроллбара?
Решения на основе jQuery, scrollbar-*-* и ::webkit-scrollbar не подходят.
Можно даже не кодом, а на словах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
        <div id='main'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
        <div id='scroll'></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100px; 
        top: 50px; 
        height: 300px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #scroll {
        width: 10px;
        height: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        background: #555;
        border-radius: 100%
    }
    #main {
        position: relative;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
    var get = function(obj) {
    return document.getElementById(obj)
},
height = get('container').offsetHeight,
top,
scrollHeight = 50;
get('scroll').onmousemove = function(e) {
    get('scroll').style.top = e.clientY - get('container').offsetTop + 'px';
    get('main').style.top = (-e.clientY - get('container').offsetTop + 50) * (get('main').offsetHeight / height) + height + 'px';
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bya7damf/)

Answer (score 1):

> Решения на основе jQuery, scrollbar-- и ::webkit-scrollbar не подходят

Ну тогда - магия!